# set action to menu icon android toolbar

Tags: icons, android-toolbar, searchview, optionmenu

I am having a Toolbar in my application with **SearchView** Widget and there are two icons one for search icon and the other is just a simple having grid drawable. when  ever I click the search button my **toolbar** is changes into SearchView but when ever I touch the grid button my toolbar again the **SearchView** becomes visible however I don't want to open **SearchView** on grid button click. I only want it to be visible for my search button.

**Code:**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.vid_search_menu_items, menu);
        //Add Tint to icon
        Drawable drawable = menu.findItem(R.id.action_grid).getIcon();
        drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white));
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_grid).setIcon(drawable);


        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when collapsed
                //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"collapsed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                searchMeta.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when expanded
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"expanded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                searchMeta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;  // Return true to expand action view
            }
        });

       return  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_search:
               Toast.makeText(this,"search",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            case R.id.action_grid:
                Toast.makeText(this,"search",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isList = !isList;
                if(isList){
                    //Change Item Icon
                    Drawable myDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_list_2);
                    myDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(myDrawable);
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(myDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white));
                    item.setIcon(myDrawable);
                }else{
                    Drawable myDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_grid_2);
                    myDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(myDrawable);
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(myDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white));
                    item.setIcon(myDrawable);
                }
                break;

        }
```

**Toolbar Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"


    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_frag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/tool_bar_icon"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Videos"
                android:id="@+id/page_title"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/search_meta"

    >
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/brands"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:popupBackground="#fff"
        android:theme="@style/CustomSpinnerStyle"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:theme="@style/CustomSpinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/categories"
android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:popupBackground="#fff"

        />


</LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**items file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:tint="@color/white"


        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_grid"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_grid_2"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:tint="@color/white"



        />


</menu>
```

Comment: Hi! Happy new year! :) Try this: `searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` or: `searchView.setVisible(false);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` from the second item and see the magic :)